# Find a block of continuous set/unset bits

Tags: c, operating-system, bitset

I am looking for a way to find a continuous block of set or unset bits in a bitset, for example in the bitset `01010111010` if i am looking for 3 set bits, i want to get 6 as result (counting from 1, would be 5 if i'd count from 0).

Also, this is for OS-dev, so there is no stdlib which can do this for me.

Comment: What if it was 1110111011?

Comment: Then i'd not really care which one i'd get. I use a bitset for allocated/free pages in memory and sometimes i need for example 3 pages of continuous memory, so I need to find 3 continuous set bits.

Comment: Please elaborate. What is your situation? What datatypes? What did you try?

Comment: Datatype is an array of uint32_t, 32 of them, for a sum of 1024 bits. I've tried to find the first 1 and then from there on count the next 1's, if they're not enough, go back, find the next 1, count from there, but this seems to be completely stupid and inefficient.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this question because the accepted answer on the linked duplicate is a C/C++ library recommendation with an off-site link, which is supposed to be off-topic, and also this question is tagged just C

Comment: Also, this question is about the special case of 3 bits in a row, not an arbitrary number.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you are looking for 3 consecutive bits in an integer n.

First, bit-wise AND the value with itself shifted 1 and 2 bits to the right:

```
n = n & (n >> 1) & (n >> 2);
```

Now only bits that are the start of a sequence of 3 consecutive bits (starting from the LSB) are set.

You can do this in a loop for an arbitrary (but small) run length if you need to check for more than 3 in a row.

Then, find the first bit that is set (counting from the least significant bit as bit 0), using a fast bit-manipulation [algorithm](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightLinear) for counting trailing zeros in a binary number.

With this approach you can search 32 or 64 bits at a time using only a few operations. However it will get more complicated if you are looking in a string of 32 or 64 bit integers, but you can just repeat the process for each word, shifting in the lower bits from the next int during the first step.

It's also not optimal if the number of consecutive bits you are looking for is large.

Comment: Thats actually a really nice way, and thanks a lot for that link!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an order N method, best described by an example.

Suppose your number is x.

To find 3 consecutive 1 bits, start with the n = 7. (That's 0b111.) Compute x & n. If that is x, then you have 3 consecutive 1 bits at the end of your number.

If not bitwise shift n to get 0b1110. Compute x & n again.

Continue until you've reached (and tested) the most significant 1 bit in x.

There are perhaps more efficient ways, for example, overlaying 0b1110111 which will require fewer shifts but a more complicated expression for success.

Answer (score 2):

Without code, but a way to do it: create a shiftregister that holds the number of bits you want to count, then shift your bitstream to it (keeping track with a counter). If your shiftregister holds all ones, you're done. The counter will then be the location.

Note that most computers use little-endian notation, so you'll have to do some shifting, copying, etc to create your bitstream.

Comment: With shiftregister you mean the last x bits set where x is the number of set bits i need? Sounds good

Comment: @tkausl that could be an implementation, yes